# Is there a way to prevent scrolling up using ng-click in the view?

Tags: html, angularjs

When I click in a link my page scrolls up, I know if I handle this inside the controller I can put an `event.preventDefault()` there, but I don't want this on controller.

Is there a way to handle this in my view?

```
        <li ng-hide="showMore">
            <a href="#" ng-click="showMore=!showMore">
                <span class="fa fa-plus-circle"></span> <br>
                Mais 
            </a>
        </li>
        <li ng-class="{'active':showMore}" ng-show="showMore">
            <a href="#" ng-click="showMore=!showMore">
                <span class="fa fa-minus-circle"></span> <br>
                Menos 
            </a>
        </li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would remove the `<a>` tag altogether and replace it with a span.

```
<span class="link" data-ng-click="showMore = !showMore">
  <span class="fa fa-plus-circle"></span> <br>
    Mais
  </span>
</span>
```

CSS

```
span.link {
    cursor:pointer;
    color:blue;
}

span.link:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `<a>` tag does not to have the `href` attribute. Removing it should help.

Also, semantically, this is not a link, but a button, so it would be more correct to use `<input type="button">` or `<button>` tag instead of `<a>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use "#!"
Like this:

```
        <li ng-hide="showMore">
        <a href="#!" ng-click="showMore=!showMore">
            <span class="fa fa-plus-circle"></span> <br>
            Mais 
        </a>
    </li>
    <li ng-class="{'active':showMore}" ng-show="showMore">
        <a href="#!" ng-click="showMore=!showMore">
            <span class="fa fa-minus-circle"></span> <br>
            Menos 
        </a>
    </li>
```

Comment: My homepage is localhost:3000/#!/ so this doesn't work for me